# Will the asking policy ever be updated?

Tags: discussion, policy

Today I was about to ask a question and came across this

[image]

This is from my dba stack account and you can check that I have not asked more than 3 or 4 questions which I believe none needed updates or edits, then to my surprise I found out that it is a privilege to ask questions in a Q&A website.
Then clicking on the link I realized that this was last updated on OCT 4 2010 so my question is will this ever be updated? I've had a very bad experience with SE on average but this is by far the most toxic and unwelcoming thing I've come across

Comment: That's when the *blog post* was written announcing the How to Ask feature. That date will never change. But the help center article itself was updated as recently as July 2017.

Comment: It typically takes more than 4 questions to become question banned, and as of today, you only have a single question which was closed for being a duplicate.  If you have more questions, then they were deleted, either by you or the community.  I am sorry to hear you feel that, not allowing you to ask more questions is toxic behavior, but hopefully you were given feedback to your now deleted questions.  Any specific feedback about your past questions at DBA can be requested [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/).  Likewise, you can do nothing, and in 6 months, you can ask another question.

Comment: You've probably got downvoted deleted toxic questions. Flag one of your current questions and ask for help locating them so you can detox and undelete.

Comment: Are you talking about a different account? You only have two questions on DBA on this account and you're not question banned...

Answer (score 9):

I'm sorry to hear you find the content on the sites within in the SE network toxic and unwelcoming.

The site offers a good [tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour), an [help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help), per site [meta's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) and moderation tools and [privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) for the community members to curate all the content that is posted on the sites.

Anyone with an account can ask or answer a question where the premises is that the provided content is deemed useful (in scope, unique, clear) for future visitors. For everything that happens on any SE site today, there is [history](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/reference/), a thought process, design, lessons learned and we're proud of that history which is why you find links to that in various places. The current articles in the help centre are an example of the learning and adapting organism any SE site is. As such the help center article is up to date but you're free to discuss changes that will help to improve our content, both old and new.

If you revisit what is offered and carefully consider that I can't imagine you won't find that valuable. It is up to you if you like our approach enough to give an SE site another go. We're happy to have you.